# Setting start time from previous night without dates from CSV using pandas

Tags: python-3.x, csv, pandas, time-series, python-datetime

tI would like to run timeseries analysis on repeated measures data (time only, no dates) taken **overnight from 22:00:00 to 09:00:00 the next morning**.

How is the time set so that the Timeseries starts at 22:00:00. At the moment even when plotting it starts at 00:00:00 and ends at 23:00:00 with a flat line between 09:00:00 and 23:00:00?

```
df = pd.read_csv('1310.csv', parse_dates=True)
df['Time'] =  pd.to_datetime(df['Time'])
df['Time'].apply( lambda d : d.time() )
df = df.set_index('Time')
df['2017-05-16 22:00:00'] + pd.Timedelta('-1 day')
```

Note: The *date* in the last line of code is automatically added, seen when `df['Time']` is executed, so I inserted the same format with date in the last line for 22:00:00.

This is the error:

```
TypeError: Could not operate Timedelta('-1 days +00:00:00') with block values unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'numpy.ndarray' and 'Timedelta'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should consider your timestamps as `pd.Timedeltas` and add a day to the samples before your start time.

Create some example data:

```
import pandas as pd
d = pd.date_range(start='22:00:00', periods=12, freq='h')
s = pd.Series(d).dt.time
df = pd.DataFrame(pd.np.random.randn(len(s)), index=s, columns=['value'])
df.to_csv('data.csv')

df
            value
22:00:00    -0.214977
23:00:00    -0.006585
00:00:00    0.568259
01:00:00    0.603196
02:00:00    0.358124
03:00:00    0.027835
04:00:00    -0.436322
05:00:00    0.627624
06:00:00    0.168189
07:00:00    -0.321916
08:00:00    0.737383
09:00:00    1.100500
```

Read in, make index a timedelta, add a day to timedeltas before the start time, then assign back to the index.

```
df2 = pd.read_csv('data.csv', index_col=0)
df2.index = pd.to_timedelta(df2.index)
s = pd.Series(df2.index)
s[s < pd.Timedelta('22:00:00')] += pd.Timedelta('1d')
df2.index = pd.to_datetime(s)

df2
                    value
1970-01-01 22:00:00 -0.214977
1970-01-01 23:00:00 -0.006585
1970-01-02 00:00:00 0.568259
1970-01-02 01:00:00 0.603196
1970-01-02 02:00:00 0.358124
1970-01-02 03:00:00 0.027835
1970-01-02 04:00:00 -0.436322
1970-01-02 05:00:00 0.627624
1970-01-02 06:00:00 0.168189
1970-01-02 07:00:00 -0.321916
1970-01-02 08:00:00 0.737383
1970-01-02 09:00:00 1.100500
```

If you want to set the date of the first day:

```
df2.index += (pd.Timestamp('2015-06-06') - pd.Timestamp(0))

df2
                    value
2015-06-06 22:00:00 -0.214977
2015-06-06 23:00:00 -0.006585
2015-06-07 00:00:00 0.568259
2015-06-07 01:00:00 0.603196
2015-06-07 02:00:00 0.358124
2015-06-07 03:00:00 0.027835
2015-06-07 04:00:00 -0.436322
2015-06-07 05:00:00 0.627624
2015-06-07 06:00:00 0.168189
2015-06-07 07:00:00 -0.321916
2015-06-07 08:00:00 0.737383
2015-06-07 09:00:00 1.100500
```

Comment: That worked perfectly! Thank you so much. **Very helpful** :)